# How can I update a column from a SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to update a column for multiple users. I have taken 3 characters from their first name and 2 characters from their last and have created an Alias. How do I update a column in another table with the data from the created alias concurrent with another value such as a contact's serial number?

```
Select DISTINCT FULLNAME,
    concat(Substring(FULLNAME, 1, 3), substring(FULLNAME, charindex(' ', 
    FULLNAME)+1, 2)) as PIC,
    CONTACT.SERIALNO,
    PASSWD
From CONTACT
    Join CONTPOINT on CONTPOINT.SERIALNO = CONTACT.SERIALNO
        and CONTPOINT.CONTTYPE = CONTACT.CONTTYPE
    Join CONTLIST on CONTLIST.REFSERIALNO = CONTACT.SERIALNO
        and CONTLIST.REFCONTTYPE = CONTACT.CONTTYPE
Where
    --left(CONTACT.fullname,4) in ()
    PASSWD in ('ADDRESS FOR THE SITE', 'ADDRESS OF SITE', 'ADDRESS OF 
    SITE', 'ADDRESS FOR THE SITE', 'ADDRESS OF SITE', 'ADDRESS OF SITE', 
    'THE SITE"S STREET NAME')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your question is not very clear. See [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some ideas on what you need to post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UPDATE FROM` syntax for that.
Lets call your `SELECT` statement ORIGINAL and the "other table" you want to update OTHER.

To use the `UPDATE FROM`:

```
UPDATE
    OTHER
  SET 
    COLUMN_TO_UPDATE = ORIGINAL.PIC
  FROM 
    OtherTable OTHER
    INNER JOIN  
      (Select DISTINCT FULLNAME,
              concat(Substring(FULLNAME, 1, 3), substring(FULLNAME, charindex(' ', 
              FULLNAME)+1, 2)) as PIC,
              CONTACT.SERIALNO,
              PASSWD
          From CONTACT
              Join CONTPOINT on CONTPOINT.SERIALNO = CONTACT.SERIALNO
                  and CONTPOINT.CONTTYPE = CONTACT.CONTTYPE
              Join CONTLIST on CONTLIST.REFSERIALNO = CONTACT.SERIALNO
                  and CONTLIST.REFCONTTYPE = CONTACT.CONTTYPE
          Where
              --left(CONTACT.fullname,4) in ()
              PASSWD in ('ADDRESS FOR THE SITE', 'ADDRESS OF SITE', 'ADDRESS OF 
              SITE', 'ADDRESS FOR THE SITE', 'ADDRESS OF SITE', 'ADDRESS OF SITE', 
              'THE SITE"S STREET NAME')) ORIGINAL
      ON (ORIGINAL.SERIALNO = OTHER.SERIALNO)
  WHERE 
    <conditions on OTHER to update>;
```